# bounds of inregral: integral (from 0 to -pi)x^2*e^{-inx}dx=integral (from pi to 0)x^2*(e^{inx})dx

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{-\pi}x^2e^{-inx} \, \text{d}x = \int_{\pi}^0 x^2e^{inx} \, \text{d}x$$ which law allows such equality? why are they equal? I was thinking it is about putting $t=x-\pi$ but during my lecture I was told it is immediately equal...

Comment: Put $t = -x{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = -t$, $dx = -dt$,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{-\pi} x^2 e^{-inx}dx 
&= \int_0^{\pi} (-t)^2 e^{int}(-dt)\\
&= \int^0_{\pi} t^2 e^{int}dt\\
&= \int^0_{\pi} x^2 e^{inx}dx
\end{align*}$$